# Saving Data on Parent Window from a Child Window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, showdialog

I have a Windows application.

The windows application has our XML Library on it.

```
  public NetspotXMLLibV1 XMLLib;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XMLLib = new XmlLibrary.NetspotXMLLibV1();
    }
```

It also has a custom control.

That custom control has a button on it that has

```
SelectWidgitWindow widgit = new SelectWidgitWindow();
widgit.ShowDialog();
```

when clicking a button, it opens up the new window. I do some stuff on this new window. When I click a button on the new window I want to save stuff on the  Form1 Window

How do I access this on my new Window (SelectWidgitWindow ) ?

Ie

```
form1.XMLLib.Add(ItemForProcessing);
```

or

```
Windows(1).XMLLib.Add(ItemForProcessing);
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ShowDialog overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) to which you can pass an owner for the new form:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.ShowDialog(this.Parent);
```

and in Form2:

```
((Form1)Owner).MyProperty = 11;
```

Comment: the f.ShowDialog(this) = this would equal the usercontrol, not the parent form

Comment: In a UserControl you can use the Parent property to access the form where the control is placed (you might want to loop through the parents until you find a form to support nested controls). See edit.

Comment: cool done using       var parent = (Form1)this.Parent;


            widgit.XMLLib = parent.XMLLib;

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways:

1) Expose the items you want the parent form to extract as properties of the child form.  In the parent form's code, when `ShowDialog` returns you can get the values you want to save from the properties.

2) Pass a reference to the parent form to the form (perhaps when it's constructed).  Then the child form can call some method or set some properties on the parent form. Note that this is *not* preferred as it couples the child for to the parent form, meaning it couldn't be called from any other form.

Comment: for 1, lets say I add the items as properties of the child window, will this then create an orphan copy those items

Comment: @WelshKing: reference (objects) types will just be references, not copies.  Value types will be copies, but it shouldn't matter.